# Can I use a generic FM 2m radio for meteor scatter or other digi modes?

Tags: digital-modes, fm, 2m-band

Firstly, I know *it’s possible*, but is there any actual activity for 2m MS. I want to get into Meteor scatter but i am wondering if i can use my 2m FM transmitter with a TNC and a yagi for meteor scatter and actually make a QSO with it while I amass materials for a large 6m yagi. Or is all of the 2m digi and MS on SSB and none on FM?

Comment: Don't think FM is a mode that makes too much sense for meteor scatter, that would usually be very low-SNR. Why do you want to specifically use that mode? I've never tried it, so I'm pretty surprised you say that you know FM meteor scatter on 2m is possible (aside, from, you know, radio astronomy-sized dishes being pointed at the meteor)!

Comment: I don’t have a 2m ssb but I I do have a 6m one that’s why I wanted to knowq

Comment: but SSB isn't FM, and I don't see how FM works with such sporadic and weak reflections? Could you refer me to how you *know it's possible*?

Comment: I’m saying in a world where there are perfect reflections with no loss and high enough power and gain and someone pre arranged on the other side decoding it, then it would most likely be possible, but I’m asking if it’s possible in the real world with not perfect reflections, a lot of losses, not impossible radio powers, and there maybe being no one on the other side

Comment: no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say wait for a 6 m yagi, or try it out on 6 m with a dipole or whatever you have. Depending where you live, there may be EME-class stations at the right distance, that mean you don't need a lot of power or a big antenna.

My limited experience with MS was on 6 m and there we used FSK441 which sends your whole (short) message many times per second. These were scheduled contacts arranged on the phone. 30 Watts SSB, 5 element Yagi, several hundred km.

When receiving, any burst that would decode correctly was also audible as a loud zzzip sound, a quarter of a second long. Quite the opposite of the JT weak signal modes you can decode but not hear. Just one good burst was enough to get part of a QSO, then in the following period you'd move on to the next step. Many audible bursts did not decode, so we didn't have a lot of margin.

I don't think that AX.25 packet would work very well with these short pings, but I do see some reports of people using APRS over MS.

Old timers told stories of meteor storms so strong and continuous they would just switch to voice...

Comment: I’ll see if I can get some contacts with my 6m and a V dipole with 10W next meteor shower if I don’t have my yagi by then

Comment: @I_like_python  but: Schedule a contact,, don't just call CQ - no one is transmitting all the time. Find someone local to you and ask them about a friendly big station 1000 km away. Even if you don't get heard with 10 W you may hear the other guy with 500 W. And no need to wait for a meteor shower! Background meteors are good enough, and in a shower they're all parallel so they only help for a small range of azimuth angles anyway. (Think of the ionized trail as a piece of wire in the sky, it scatters mostly perpendicular to the trail).

Comment: Broadcast stations (3m?) are transmitting all the time...